# Getting the percentile the item belongs to in SQL

Tags: sql, statistics, google-bigquery, percentile

I'm trying to put together some simple stats, but stuck with computing the percentile that the author belongs to according to his total scores:

```
select
    [by] author,
    count(*) count,
    sum(score) sum_score,
    quantiles(sum(score), 101) percentile_sum_score,
from
    [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.stories]
group by
    author
```

This code returns each author's `sum(score)` in the column `percentile_sum_score` (defined as `quantiles(sum(score), 101)`). But not the percentile the author is in, relative to other authors.

This happens in [BigQuery](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/), and some conventional functions are not available ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference)).

Is there a way to get the right statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [PERCENT_RANK()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#percent_rank) function
Below is possible use for your example

```
SELECT
    author,
    [count],
    sum_score,
    PERCENT_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sum_score DESC) percentile_sum_score,
FROM (
  SELECT
    [by] author,
    COUNT(1) [count],
    SUM(score) sum_score,
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.stories]
  GROUP BY author
)
```